# dpkg: error processing extlinux (--configure)

Tags: apt, package-management

So I was running `apt-get autoremove` and the output was:

```
 dpkg: error processing extlinux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 extlinux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

is it Right?

Comment: post the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Can you post the full output and also output of `sudo sh -x /var/lib/dpkg/info/extlinux.postinst`

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

1. try this this will definately solve your issue

Comment: No. the Same output as before

Comment: Any other ideas? thanx

Answer (score 0):

sames error on Kali **`*other distro based on Debian too*`**

the error was related to an incomplete installation

and solution was to check your **sources.list** in "**/etc/apt/sources.list**"

leave only trusted sources : place a # before the other line sources .

then execute : `apt-get autoremove`

and then after that execute : `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

**

### Other option

**

is to reinstall the problematic package  as following them remove it

**but be aware this package is related to syslinux  that is a boot loader and i'm not sure if it's the one that loads your machine or it's grub**

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall extlinux
```

`sudo apt-get purge extlinux` (if you are sure you don't need it)

Comment: i Dont Get It
Please Explain in a simpler language

Comment: i meant the error appeared on another version of Linux and it's similar to ubuntu , and the error was due to incomplete installation ..  they solved it in 2 ways  first to adjust the sources.list file  to only work with trusted sources  or they reinstalled the application witch is in your case the extlinux